# On a BDD flow, when/where a Feature file is written, and when/who adds it to the codebase?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Is there any good practice to that? I know it is flexible, but is there any standard to follow? Should I create the feature branches and add the .feature files on it, or add the feature files on the development branch in order to track the progress of all the features being done (live doc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using BDD, so using the feature file describing the behaviour to drive your development, the feature file should be on whatever branch you are developing said feature (this might be a feature branch, if you're using them).
In general, I find it helpful to have the feature file as close to the actual feature under development (also when using a "test after" approach, rather than BDD), because it allows you to test the feature as soon as possible, giving you fast feedback on whether it works as it should, and making it easier to fix bugs / add functionality.

Comment: cool. Yeah makes sense. Will add the feature files whenever we create a feature branch - My team is starting using BDD + Cucumber and we are trying to move the first development sprints a bit slower so we give more attention to the process, and as soon we get comfortable with it, start moving quicker. Thanks

Comment: Cool! Join us on Cucumber Slack if you'd like to discuss progress. :) Details on the https://cucumber.io/support page